# Python / Pandas - how to define the dtype of a column when Dataframe is a multi-index DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let say I have following multi-index DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
row_axis = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]], names=['Data', 'Period'])
column_axis = [['Index','Index', 'Data'],['First','Last','Min']]
MD = pd.DataFrame(index=row_axis, columns=column_axis)
```

Later on, when filling a row, I can have values like this.

```
MD.loc[('hi','5m'),:]=[5,10,'hello']
```

Checking dtypes, it tells me:

```
In [17]:MD.dtypes
Out[17]: 
Index  First    object
       Last     object
Data   Min      object
dtype: object
```

How can I convert the type in the first column ('Index', 'First')?

Trying:

```
MD = MD.astype({'(Index, First)' : int)
```

Gives:

```
KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is not possible. DataFrame dtypes are on a per-column basis.

Comment: `MD.astype({'(Index, First)' : int)` You used a string of a tuple `'(Index, First)'` when you should have used a tuple of strings `('Index', 'First')` Please see [@YOBEN_S's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548728/2336654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
MD = MD.astype({('Index', 'First') : int})
MD.dtypes
Out[53]: 
Index  First     int32
       Last      int64
Data   Min      object
dtype: object
```